# Problem with getting data from VPS when SSL is turned on

Tags: android, react-native, server, dns, vps

I'm building my first mobile app with React Native. I've got some data on my VPS server. For example, I've got an image on the server and I'm setting up image URI in my app to this image on the server. When I've got SSL turned off and the link starts with HTTP:// everything works fine only in debug mode, in release nothing happens. I tried to turn on SSL, then the link starts with HTTPS:// but I don't get any data either in debug mode or release mode.
Anyone can help me?
I didn't try on iOS yet. The problem is on android.